# How to use sed to add double quotes around every word, excluding colons and commas

Tags: regex, shell, jenkins, sed

I want to alter a **string** so that I have double quotes around every "word," excluding colons and commas ':,'.

For example, my input may look like:

> [ANALYSIS:true, RESTRICTED:false, STRING_PARAMETER:World,
> JOB_NAME:Hello_Jenkins]

but I want it to appear as

> ["ANALYSIS":"true", "RESTRICTED":"false", "STRING_PARAMETER":"World",
> "JOB_NAME":"Hello_Jenkins"]

I've been using something like (using '_' as the delimiter)

```
'echo ${params} | sed -i "s_\'/\\([^:]*\\):/i\'_\'"$1" :\'_g" '
```

based off of what I've found online, yet it makes no changes to my string.

Comment: Do you mean like this? `sed 's/\([[:alnum:]_][[:alnum:]_]*\)/"\1"/g' <<< "[ANALYSIS:true, RESTRICTED:false, STRING_PARAMETER:World, JOB_NAME:Hello_Jenkins]"` See [demo](https://tio.run/##TchNC8IgAIDhvyJeVjGQruLFSmqjLFSIUBFj9kHmYLbfb@vW7X2fq8@PUnLoQJWRmWmNfUzjG1tn/3th5giaJUT3ChBCANSU0/1FNhJ/hjHUQDCpRLNWbINvPuZJfs@37kQFPTDFBD73Q@xq0B5Xjk@EdyHG3rUhvZ4pW1jKFw)

Comment: note that the `-i` option means "--inplace" which is only helpful when you specify a filename for `sed` to process, i.e. `sed -i '/script/' file`. Good luck.

Comment: You have a bunch of `'`s in your regexp but no `'`s in your input plus a few other odd things so the regexp can never match any part of the input.

Answer (score 1):

```
> sed -r 's/[^], :[]+/"&"/g' file
["ANALYSIS":"true", "RESTRICTED":"false", "STRING_PARAMETER":"World", "JOB_NAME":"Hello_Jenkins"]
```

In the above `sed` we exclude colons, commas, the brackets and the spaces, as your example says so. If your case is not fully represented by your example, you could modify the excluded characters, but the order of the brackets in the expression is important.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo '[ANALYSIS:true, RESTRICTED:false, STRING_PARAMETER:World, JOB_NAME:Hello_Jenkins]' |
    sed 's/[[:alnum:]_]\+/"&"/g'
["ANALYSIS":"true", "RESTRICTED":"false", "STRING_PARAMETER":"World", "JOB_NAME":"Hello_Jenkins"]
```

or if you have to exclude instead of include chars in the regexp:

```
$ echo '[ANALYSIS:true, RESTRICTED:false, STRING_PARAMETER:World, JOB_NAME:Hello_Jenkins]' |
    sed 's/[^][,: ]\+/"&"/g'
["ANALYSIS":"true", "RESTRICTED":"false", "STRING_PARAMETER":"World", "JOB_NAME":"Hello_Jenkins"]
```